# adapting screen to portrait bug objective-c

Tags: objective-c, uiview, autorotate

Alright so i was having a little bit of a problem with the view when the device went into landscape so i decided to change the location of my textfields by code with this:

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]statusBarOrientation];

NSLog(@"SPIN");


if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

    CGRect frame = [self.a frame];
    frame.origin.x = 20;
    frame.origin.y = 57;
    [self.a setFrame:frame];

    CGRect frame2 = [self.b frame];
    frame2.origin.x = 20;
    frame2.origin.y = 132;
    [self.b setFrame:frame2];

    CGRect frame3 = [self.c frame];
    frame3.origin.x = 20;
    frame3.origin.y = 207;
    [self.c setFrame:frame3];


} else {

    CGRect frame = [self.a frame];
    frame.origin.x = 83;
    frame.origin.y = 21;
    [self.a setFrame:frame];

    CGRect frame2 = [self.b frame];
    frame2.origin.x = 204;
    frame2.origin.y = 21;
    [self.b setFrame:frame2];

    CGRect frame3 = [self.c frame];
    frame3.origin.x = 330;
    frame3.origin.y = 21;
    [self.c setFrame:frame3];



}

}
```

it worked just fine, everything went where it was suppost to, the problem is when click on any of the textfields to write something all of them bug out and end up looking like this:

uh.. nevermind that apparently i need at least 10 reputation before i can post an image, so here's a description of what the image showed instead:

image shows 3 uisegmented controls and 3 textfields crammed stacked on top of each other on the very top of the screen

So i'm more of a hobbyist than a pro at this so i apologize if this is a stupid question, but what am i doing wrong here? and additionaly is there a better way of going about adapting your view?

Comment: Post a link to the screenshot and a 2k user will imbed it.

Comment: This sounds like an auto layout problem. Try turning auto layout off, and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using auto layout or may be auto resizing masks on different views which you are using. There is a property called as autoresizingmask in uiview.

You can check this for reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html